# How to access an API without using api-key in robot framework

Tags: python, api, robotframework

I am new to robot framework and i am trying to automate an api using api-key.
In employee application -
API key is generated at employee level and that api-key is injected to the api. Now everytime the employee is switched i have to manually pick the api-key and inject into the configuration.
Below is my code using api-key

```
Create Session And Post Request With API Key
    [Documentation]  Input API Key Token To Authorize Platform API And Post A Request
    [Arguments]  ${request_body}  ${emp_id}  ${module_name}  ${status_code}
    create session  session  ${base_url_api}  disable_warnings=1
    &{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json  x-api-key=${api_token_key}
    ${api_response}=    post request  session    ${emp_id}/${module_name}  json=${request_body}
    ...  headers=${headers}
    log to console  API URL : ${api_response.url}
    Verify API Status Code   ${api_response}  ${status_code}
    [Return]  ${api_response}
```

I want to eliminate the dependency of api-key
Is there any other way i can access the api?

Comment: if the post requires api key to work you need to pass it some way..